# Joomla Archive extract ZIP causes "Unknown archive type"

Tags: php, joomla, zip

When trying to extract a ZIP archive like this:

```
$archive = new Archive; 
$archive->extract( 'something.ZIP', $this->tmp_directory);
```

I get

> Unknown archive type: ZIP

If I rename the file to `something.zip` the extraction works.

This only happens on the Linux Webserver. I'm running Joomla 3.9.3.

Comment: This might actually be a bug that you'd need to [create an issue](https://github.com/joomla-framework/archive/issues) for

Comment: Hmm, I'll wait if someone else says something here before opening an issue. Thanks.

Comment: It is a bug and was referenced here: https://github.com/joomla-framework/archive/commit/b0d8a6c72939f950abfb0f81147f58aa374fffcb

Comment: Never wait for someone else to say something before opening an issue.  It's better for someone to invest a few minutes confirming a report is not an issue than for something to not be reported because they don't know if they are the only one to have seen or experienced it.

Comment: Well 95% of Support Tickets we get telling there is a bug are just not knowing how things work. And developer time is important, so i rather check three times before i ask a dev to check a possible bug.

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed a bug in the Joomla Archive class (as someone suggested) since it is always expecting the file extension to be lowercase. This should be reported to the Joomla team.

Having said that, you can fix the problem temporarily by editing a core file, `libraries/vendor/joomla/archive/src/Archive.php` and adding, immediately after the following code:

```
$ext = pathinfo($archivename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

This line:

```
$ext = strtolower($ext);
```

This should fix the problem.